# Who is in the Chasm of Souls?

Tags: lara-croft-tomb-raider, tomb-raider-2018

In *Tomb Raider* (2018), the characters must cross a "Chasm of Souls" that consists of a pit with a very large number of desiccated bodies at the bottom.

Is there any indication of who these people are at the bottom?

My first guess would be that they are

> Victims of the virus

But if this were the case, wouldn't they have received a more dignified burial than being dumped into a mass grave? After all, the bodies of Himiko's handmaidens are found in individual, labeled niches rather than a mass grave.

This also goes along with Lara's conclusion that

> Himiko wasn't imprisoned for being evil, but in fact placed herself there as a public health measure so no one else would catch the zombifying virus. If that is the case, it would make sense for her to treat those she had accidentally infected as heroes deserving of decent burials, not nobodies to be dumped into a pit.

It also occurred to me that these could be ancient grave robbers, but there are an awfully large number of bodies down there for them all to be failed grave robbers. It also doesn't explain how *all* of them ended up in the pit or how they even got inside when the tomb was still sealed until the 21st century.

Answer (score -2):

2018 *Tomb Raider* film is in part based on *Tomb Raider*, the 2013 video game reboot developed by Crystal Dynamics and published by Square Enix's European subsidiary, which established elements of the film reboot origins.

> In the 2013 game, Lara Croft and her crew set out to find a lost island off the coast of Japan called Yamatai that was once ruled by Queen Himiko. They're shipwrecked by a vicious storm, but make it to the island, whose only inhabitants are members of a cult that worships Himiko, also known as the Sun Queen. It turns out this monarch has supernatural powers that include manipulating the weather and the ability to transfer her soul into new host bodies. This ruler, her shamanic powers and the area she ruled are based on history, and were recorded in Chinese classic texts as far back as the third century.
>
> <sub>[CBR.com, Who Is Tomb Raider's Mother of Death?](https://www.cbr.com/tomb-raider-2018-himiko-mother-death/)</sub>

Being based on the game, the film’s Chasm of Souls being one of Himiko’s challenges could then implied to be the final resting place for Himiko’s old, discarded vessels.

The film plot did not retain all of the elements of the 2013 game, instead establishing that Himiko carried disease.

My interpretation of the film shared your hypothesis: that the film chasm became the final resting place of Himiko’s followers inadvertently victimized by the disease, or perhaps original inhabitants of the island before Himiko arrived who then fell ill from her disease.